# Unexpected results from conditions in if, using &&

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, json, if-statement, nsmutabledictionary

I am parsing with the JSON parser. I stored the data into `searchURL`, which is an `NSMutableDictionary`. I do get a JSON response.

```
       ksearchKeyHeadline = "noresults"
       ksearchKeyNewsText = "http://172.15.12.98:8080//...... url."
       ksearchKeyIssuersText= "noresults"
```

Here I am making conditions:

```
if ([[searchURL objectForKey:KSearchKeyHeadline] isEqualToString:@"noresults"] &&
    [[searchURL objectForKey:kSearchKeyNewsText] isEqualToString:@"noresults"] &&
    [[searchURL objectForKey:kSearchKeyIssuerText] isEqualToString:@"noresults"]) {
    NSURLRequest *req;
    req=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:kSearchBarNoResult,text.text]]];
    [[[featuredAsset viewControler] iWebview] loadRequest:req];
}
else if([searchURL objectForKey:KSearchKeyHeadline]!=@"noresults" && 
        [searchURL objectForKey:kSearchKeyNewsText]!=@"noresults" && 
        [searchURL objectForKey:kSearchKeyIssuerText]!=@"noresults"){
    NSURLRequest *req;
    req=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithString:kSearchBarHeadlinesURL]]];
    [[[featuredAsset viewControler] iWebview] loadRequest:req];
}
else if([[searchURL objectForKey:kSearchKeyNewsText]isEqualToString:@"noresults"] && 
        [searchURL objectForKey:kSearchKeyNewsText]!=@"noresults" &&
        [[searchURL objectForKey:kSearchKeyIssuerText]isEqualToString:@"noresults"]){
    NSURLRequest *req;
    req=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithString:kSearchBarNewsTextURL]]];
    [[[featuredAsset viewControler]iWebview]loadRequest:req];
}
```

The problem is, it's calling both `else if` conditions. I must call the last condition. I know the ampersand `&&` will check the condition -- when the entire condition is true, it returns true. What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't compare NSStrings like this:

```
[searchURL objectForKey:KSearchKeyHeadline]!=@"noresults"
```

you need to use `isEqualToString`:

```
[[searchURL objectForKey:KSearchKeyHeadline] isEqualToString: @"noresults"]
```

Also your `ksearchKeyHeadline` is `"noresult"`, not `"noresults"`.

Comment: well its has been edited......... to noresults.  how do i compare if !=@"noresults"

Comment: @applelover - ![... isEqualToString: @"noresults"] will evaluate the opposite.